# Converting a factor into a date in R

Tags: r, date

Hey i'm new in using R so this question could be easy for many of you, but I'm really struggeling.
I have a column in my dataset called datum.
It's handled by R as an Factor
$ Datum        : Factor w/ 550 levels "1-10-2014","1-10-2015",..: 203 203 203 203 203 203 203 203 203 399 ...
When I try to convert this factor into a date, i get as result NA.
I tried several things like:

`> prijzen$Datum <- as.Date(prijzen$Datum, format='%d/%m/%y')`

`> prijzen$Datum<- as.Date(as.character(prijzen$Datum), format="%d/%m/%y")`

Even reading in the file with stringsAsFactors = FALSE didn't help.
How could i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO and to R. Hmm how does the format `"%d/%m/%y"` resonate with `1-10-2014`? There is no slash but a minus as a seperator.

Comment: You're right! I changed it to "%d-%m/%y", but this results in 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03 and so on....

Comment: Have a look at `?strptime`: Among other things, it explains the difference between `%Y` and `%y` (which is a common trap for errors).

Comment: Ok. It's working now I get the right dates. But it's still classified as chr. Like: Datum : chr "02-01-2014" "02-01-2014" "02-01-2014" "02-01-2014"

Comment: It's a character vector if you use `format(...)`, and it's a data vector if you use `as.Date(prijzen$Datum, format='%d-%m-%Y')`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong, you can use:

```
prijzen <- data.frame(Datum = c("1-10-2014","1-10-2015"), prijs = c(125, 150)) 
prijzen$Datum <- as.Date(prijzen$Datum, format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

This will format the Datum column as a Date and can be used in date calculations. The default format in R follows the rules of the ISO 8601 international standard which expresses a day as "2001-02-03"

But have a look at the way you are reading in the data. If, for example, you are using read.csv, try to specify the columns with the option `colClasses`.

Edit based on comments, formatted the output as well so the result in in dd-mm-yyyy format and not in standard iso format:

```
prijzen$Datum <- format(as.Date(prijzen$Datum, format='%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

This will transform the Datum column to a character column. This is more for printing the dates or exporting them.

Comment: You're right! I changed it to "%d-%m/%y", but this results in 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03 and so on....

Comment: based on you edit, the thing is that I lose information. There is no longer a difference between the several years. R makes all the years 2020 instead of 2014, 2015 or 2016.

Comment: Yess I'm using the capital Y. It also gives the class character.

Comment: This is the code I'm using. Prijzen will contain the column Datum as a factor. after using the format and as.Date function it will be transformed as a Date.
`prijzen <- data.frame(Datum = c("1-10-2014","1-10-2015"), prijs = c(125, 150))`
`prijzen$Datum <- format(as.Date(prijzen$Datum, format='%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: Ok. It's working now I get the right dates. But it's still classified as chr. Like: Datum        : chr  "02-01-2014" "02-01-2014" "02-01-2014" "02-01-2014"